# OOP factory method vs constructor

Tags: php, factory-pattern

I have one top class, let's say School.

And a couple of classes extending the School class.

Normally, if I had to call one of the child classes I would use:

`new Math('aaa')`, or `new English(array('foo'))`;

Every child class has different parameters.

Now, what is better:

1) Creating factory method in the School class, so :

`School::Factory('aaa')` would return `Math('aaa')` class based on the given parameters to the Factory() method

2) Or simply calling each child classes directly?

EDIT: I have only two child classes, my problem is that I don't know if doing this is worth a bit of simplicity in production code. I would just check which parameters were passed to the Factory method, and based on this information I'd call one of these two classes. What do you think?

On one side I'll be able to write simpler code.
On the other every time I'll need to add new child class (though there are very little chances to do that), I'll need to change Factory() method either, so I have a dependency here.

Comment: I don't think that general advice can be given on this subject, you will always need to consider the specific structure of your components.

Comment: edited, check this out now

Comment: What's minus for? A chance for a better design decision was worth asking this question :P

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Creating factory method in the School class, so :

You say that you have 2 classes extending School. Therefore, School **should not** act as a factory. The parent class shouldn't know anything about its children/subclasses.

> 2) Or simply calling each child classes directly?

Or you could have a "CourseFactory" or "LectureFactory" with `createMath( aaa )`, for example. Or depending on the case, maybe `createLecture("math")`.

However, it makes no sense in your example that Math or English *extend* School (unless you mean MathSchool and EnglishSchool, but I understood it as MathCourse and EnglishCourse)